# Swift generic convert error

Tags: swift, generics

code as below:

```
class Animall<T> {
    var value: T?
}

protocol Type {
    var name: String {get set}
}


class Duck: Type {
    var name = "duck"
}

var d = Animall<Duck>()
var duck = Duck()
duck.name = "duck"
d.value = duck

if let finalD = d as? Animall<Type> {
    print(finalD.value?.name)
}
else {
    print("Can't Convert")
}
```

It's Always log "Can't Convert". I want know the reason. I'm so puzzled.
Duck is conform Type protocol. Why doesn't it convert!

Answer (score 0):

`Animal<Duck>` is not a "subclass" of `Animal<Type>` even if `Duck` conforms to the protocol `Type`. They are different classes, and this due to the fact that Swift generic types are invariant in respect to their generic argument. This means that every time you refer `Animal` with a different type, regardless the inheritance, the `Animal` "instances" are actually different, incompatible, types.

You can work around this "limitation" by moving the processing code to a generic function that operates on `Type`:

```
func doSomething<T: Type>(with animal: Animal<T>) {
    print(animal.value?.name)
}

doSomething(with: d)
```